# Getting tags and tag count using the tumblr api json feed [jquery]

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, api, tumblr

I'm having a bit of a tricky problem with the tumblr api. I am currently getting every tag from all my posts and storing it in an array. However that means that if an array is used more than once it doubles up. I want to be able to just store a tag once only and also store how many times it's appeared. Any ideas? I was thinking an object array would work but I am struggling with working out if the tag has already been put into the array and how to update the "count" value.

```
var allTags = [];
var start = 0;
var cleanTags = [];

$(function() {


tumblrTag = function(tag,count) {
    this.Tag = tag;
    this.Count = count;        
}

getTags()

});

function getTags() {

    var tumblrApi = 'http://blog.rainbird.me/api/read/json?callback=?&num=50&start=' + start;

      $.getJSON(tumblrApi, function (data) {

        $(data.posts).each(function (i, post) {
          $(post.tags).each(function (i, tag) {

            if (typeof (tag) === 'string') {

            newTag = new tumblrTag(tag, "1");

            allTags.push(newTag);


            }

          });
        });
        if (start + 50 < data['posts-total']) {
          start = start + 50;
          getTags();
        } else {
         console.log("complete");
         console.log(allTags);
        }
      });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2UML/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
obj[tag] = count;
```

and when you get new tags use something along the lines of

```
if( obj[newtag] ){
  obj[newtag] += 1;
}else{
  obj[newtag] = 1;
}
```